# Stop logging ActionController::RoutingError Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger

How to disable logging for **ActionController::RoutingError** Errors?
My production log file is full of **bots** searching for phpMyAdmin and other stuff.
Then the real application errors are overlooked.
Please help. I'm running Rails 3.2 and Passenger.

In my routes.rb I map all other urls to `get ":code" => "shared#code"`, and then, if not found, i display a page with message. But when the bot search for urls like `http://mywebsite.com/phpMyAdmin/index.php`, the classic error page is shown "The page you were looking for doesn't exist.". Which is ok. But i just dont want to log these errors in the log file.

Comment: Thank you for asking exactly the same question I was about to ask.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The thing that logs/displays errors is the `ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions` middleware. You could just overwrite the `log_error` method, for example stick this in an initialiser:

```
class ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions
  alias_method :old_log_error, :log_error
  def log_error(env, wrapper)
    if wrapper.exception.is_a?  ActionController::RoutingError
      return
    else
      old_log_error env, wrapper
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But may i ask you, where exactley i should put this? I mean which file and folder.

Comment: initialisers live in config/initializers

Comment: I once attempted to remove the DebugExceptions from production environment, but it was more trouble than it solved, so I had to put them back. Too bad I didn't write down what was the problem with this approach.

Comment: Don't know to be honest