# How can I get Rails 3.0 to not attempt to route a specific path, or at least not log it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, logging, routes

I'm trying to debug an issue on my development machine, but I've got production data loaded into the database. As a result, I've got a lot of image paths that don't have a matching file on the system so Rails tries to resolve them all through the routing table. I've figured out how to ignore the `ActionController::RoutingError` messages thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/12227802/83743, but I'm still getting more noise in the server logs than I would like. Is there a way to tell Rails to not even attempt to resolve any route matching a specific pattern? Alternately, is there a way to hide all of the `Started GET "/system/attachments/...` log entries? I'm using Rails 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you could modify this initializer:

```
if Rails.env.development?
  Rails.application.assets.logger = Logger.new('/dev/null')
  Rails::Rack::Logger.class_eval do
    def call_with_quiet_assets(env)
      previous_level = Rails.logger.level
      Rails.logger.level = Logger::ERROR if env['PATH_INFO'] =~ %r{^/assets/}
      call_without_quiet_assets(env)
    ensure
      Rails.logger.level = previous_level
    end
    alias_method_chain :call, :quiet_assets
  end
end
```

from this question: [How to disable logging of asset pipeline (sprockets) messages in Rails 3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312448/how-to-disable-logging-of-asset-pipeline-sprockets-messages-in-rails-3-1) to exclude your preferred logs.